# Get Value from generic interface

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

if I have a class like this :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDbContext
```

how can I get some properties of `ApplicationUser`inside `ApplicationDbContext`  ?

Comment: You can't necessarily get properties of it.

Comment: `ApplicationUser` is a type parameter, not an instance. It has no properties, though you could get the property metadata through the type. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: ok , could anyone explain me what is wrong with this question ?

Comment: @Jeroen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649510/entity-framework-get-user-from-contex-in-savechanges

Comment: @kosnkov: Is that your actual question? It looks like it, since it's a whole lot more detailed than this one. Please don't create duplicates of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the following program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var calc = new Calculator<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(calc.Add(1,1));
    }
}

class Calculator<T>
{
    public int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

There is no way to get any string-like properties from the calculator.

The reason is that `string` is a type parameter, not an object. Whether or not the class makes properties accessible depends on many other factors. A `List<T>` allows to get objects of type T back, but other classes needn't do that.