# How to set created date and Modified Date to enitites in DB first approach

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

In every SQL table in our application we have "CreatedDate" and "ModifiedDate" column. We are using DB first approach. When i save the data, i want these two column automatically populated. One approach is to have Default Value as `getdate()` on the SQL Table Column itself. So thats going to solve the problem partially. Meaning it will set the CreatedDate & ModifiedDate when entity is new.
However when i am editing/updating the entity i want only `ModifiedDate` to be updated.
There are lot of articles doing it using Code first approach. But we are using DB first approach.
What are my options here?

Comment: Override SaveChanges in your context. http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent344.aspx

Comment: If you already use default values from the database then it should also be the database that modifies `ModifiedDate` by a trigger. It's never guaranteed that client clocks match. That said, I'd use triggers for this *always*.

Answer (score 26):

See this answer for `.NET Core`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64824067/3850405

I like a more generic approach used like this:

```
interface IEntityDate
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}

public abstract class EntityBase<T1>: IEntityDate
{
    public T1 Id { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

    foreach (var changedEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        if (changedEntity.Entity is IEntityDate entity)
        {
            switch (changedEntity.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entity.CreatedDate = now;
                    entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Modified:
                    Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
                    entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Update:**

To handle `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy` I use a wrapper for DbContext like this:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public interface ICurrentUser
{
    string GetUsername();
}

public class ApplicationDbContextUserWrapper
{
    public ApplicationDbContext Context;

    public ApplicationDbContextUserWrapper(ApplicationDbContext context, ICurrentUser currentUser)
    {
        context.CurrentUser = currentUser;
        this.Context = context;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{

    public ICurrentUser CurrentUser;
    
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        foreach (var changedEntity in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (changedEntity.Entity is IEntity entity)
            {
                switch (changedEntity.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        entity.CreatedDate = now;
                        entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                        entity.CreatedBy = CurrentUser.GetUsername();
                        entity.UpdatedBy = CurrentUser.GetUsername();
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedBy).IsModified = false;
                        Entry(entity).Property(x => x.CreatedDate).IsModified = false;
                        entity.UpdatedDate = now;
                        entity.UpdatedBy = CurrentUser.GetUsername();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    
    ...
```

Comment: how are you setting, UpdatedBy?

Comment: @IvanSalo Updated my answer with how I solved this.

Comment: how about i want to override the autocreation and want to set it manually in the controllers

Comment: Wow this worked great for me!! Thanks a lot @Ogglas!!

Comment: The question was for Database First approach. This will not work for Database First as the context file gets generated.

Comment: @Kellie It is possible to create the specialized class (ApplicationDbContext) as demonstrated in the update, or to put the override in a partial class file.

Answer (score 20):

For those who are using asynchronous system (SaveChangesAsync) and .net core better to add below code to DbContext class.

```
    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var AddedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();

        AddedEntities.ForEach(E =>
        {
            E.Property("CreationTime").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
        });

        var EditedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

        EditedEntities.ForEach(E =>
        {
            E.Property("ModifiedDate").CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
        });

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
```

and also you can define a class or interface like below.

```
public class SaveConfig
{
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

just inherit entities from the SaveConfig entity.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Also, if you _do_ inherit from the `SaveConfig`, you can use `ChangeTracker.Entries<SaveConfig>()...` and then replace `E.Property("CreationTime").CurrentValue` with `E.Entity.CreationTime`, avoiding magic strings :)

Comment: This worked like a charm. I used your code to override `SaveChangesAsync()` and [this code](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/set-created-and-modified-date-in-efcore.aspx) to override `SaveChanges()`.

Answer (score 20):

If you'd like to override OnSave you have to override all save methods.In EF core 2.1 you can use better solution with ChangeTracked and events. For example:

You can create interface or base class like example below:

```
public interface IUpdateable 
{ 
    DateTime ModificationDate{ get; set; }
}

public class SampleEntry : IUpdateable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then on context creation add event to Change tracker:

```
context.ChangeTracker.StateChanged += context.ChangeTracker_StateChanged;
```

And method:

```
private void ChangeTracker_StateChanged(object sender, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Entry.Entity is IUpdateable && e.Entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            var entry = ((IUpdateable)e.Entry.Entity);
            entry.ModificationDate = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
```

It's easier and you don't have to override all methods.

Comment: See this post to read a related thread and have a more detailed solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187146/populate-created-and-lastmodified-automagically-in-ef-core#answer-53188193

Answer (score 10):

You can override SaveChanges method in DbContext and get a list of Added and Modified your entity and if it is added set CreatedDate and if it is modified set ModifiedDate.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var AddedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<Entity>().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();

    AddedEntities.ForEach(E => 
    {
        E.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    });

    var ModifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries<Entity>().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

    ModifiedEntities.ForEach(E => 
    {
        E.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    });

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

You can also write an interface which has two DateTime property and make your Entities inherit them.

```
interface IEntityDate
{
    DateTime AddedDate { set; get;}
    DateTime ModifiedDate { set; get;}
}

class Entity : IEntityDate
{
    public DateTime AddedDate { set; get;}
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { set; get;}
}
```

Comment: well entities are created by T4. Those entities are not derived from any interface. So i guess i have to modify that T4, right?

Comment: @LP13 My bad! if you are using Db first, you can't use interface. I think the only solution is that you add these two columns in your database and then update your model

Comment: Small nitpick, but I would also recommend storing the CreatedDate and ModifedDate using `DateTime.UtcNow` to avoid dealing with time zone issues.

Answer (score 7):

From EF-Core 5x onwards, you can use interceptors and outside the `DbContext` instead of overriding the `SaveChanges` method.

Its general format looks like this:

```
public class AuditableEntitiesInterceptor : SaveChangesInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult<int> SavingChanges(
        DbContextEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<int> result)
    {
        if (eventData == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventData));
        }

        BeforeSaveTriggers(eventData.Context);
        return result;
    }

     public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> SavingChangesAsync(
        DbContextEventData eventData,
        InterceptionResult<int> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (eventData == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(eventData));
        }

        BeforeSaveTriggers(eventData.Context);
        return ValueTask.FromResult(result);
    }

    private void BeforeSaveTriggers(DbContext? context)
    {
        var entries = context?.ChangeTracker
                .Entries()
                .Where(e => e.Entity is BaseEntity && (
                     e.State == EntityState.Added
                     || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entityEntry in entries)
        {
            ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).UpdatedDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;

        if (entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((BaseEntity)entityEntry.Entity).CreatedDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

You can use of `ChangeTracker` in `BeforeSaveTriggers` method to track the entity changes.

Because this interceptor uses dependency injection, it needs to be registered as a service.

```
services.AddSingleton<AuditableEntitiesInterceptor>();
```

Then it can be taken from dependency injection in the startup of the program and introduced to the context.

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>((serviceProvider, optionsBuilder) =>
                optionsBuilder
                    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
                    .AddInterceptors(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AuditableEntitiesInterceptor>()));
```

Worth noting that this sample `BaseEntity` uses `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime` for a better localization, you can adjust your implementation as needed.

```
 public class BaseEntity{ 
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset UpdatedDate { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Do I need to extend all my models to use the BaseEntity class?

Comment: Entities that need to have these two dates must inherit from BaseEntity.

Comment: This answer is the most up-to-date, and leverages dependency injection without needing to override context methods.

Answer (score 3):

I did a similar thing to what @Arash proposed with the public override "Task SaveChangesAsync" with the difference that with my setup I just want to update the entities that actually have a CreatedDate/ModifiedDate properties and this is what I came up with. Very similar to @Arash, but maybe it can help someone. 
Added a couple of constants EntityCreatedPropertyName and EntityModifiedPropertyName defining the name of the properties so that I would not have to use duplicated strings for those where ever I use them.

```
    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        #region Automatically set "CreatedDate" property on an a new entity
        var AddedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();

        AddedEntities.ForEach(E =>
        {
            var prop = E.Metadata.FindProperty(EntityCreatedPropertyName);
            if (prop != null)
            {
                E.Property(EntityCreatedPropertyName).CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            }
        });
        #endregion

        #region Automatically set "ModifiedDate" property on an a new entity
        var EditedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

        EditedEntities.ForEach(E =>
        {
            var prop = E.Metadata.FindProperty(EntityModifiedPropertyName);
            if (prop != null)
            {
                E.Property(EntityModifiedPropertyName).CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
            }
        });
        #endregion

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I solved in EF Core 2.1:

I have a base model which inherits an interface similar to:

```
public interface IAuditableModel
{
    DateTime Created { get; }
    DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel : IAuditableModel
{
    public BaseModel()
    {
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; private set; }

    public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in my DbContext:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var added = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditableModel>().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();

        added.ForEach(E =>
        {
            E.Property(x => x.Created).CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
            E.Property(x => x.Created).IsModified = true;
        });

        var modified = ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditableModel>().Where(E => E.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

        modified.ForEach(E =>
        {
            E.Property(x => x.Updated).CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
            E.Property(x => x.Updated).IsModified = true;

            E.Property(x => x.Created).CurrentValue = E.Property(x => x.Created).OriginalValue;
            E.Property(x => x.Created).IsModified = false;
        });

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This allows you to avoid hard coding any property names, and lets you flexibly apply the specific interface to models of your choosing. In my case I want this on most models so I applied to my BaseModel which all other models inherit from.

As well I was finding on my views that edited these models the created timestamp was getting wiped out since I was not loading it onto the page. As a result when the model was bound on postback that property was erased setting my created timestamps to 0 effectively.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of the more generic ways to do it.

Configure entity like this:
Don't forget to add "SetAfterSaveBehavior AND SetBeforeSaveBehavior " to avoid throwing an exception by inserting a null value

```
builder.Property(p => p.ModifiedDate)
  .HasValueGenerator<DateTimeGenerator>()
  .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()
  .Metadata.SetAfterSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Save);            
builder.Property(p => p.ModifiedDate)
  .Metadata.SetBeforeSaveBehavior(PropertySaveBehavior.Save);
```

how to write the class DateTimeGenerator :

```
internal class DateTimeGenerator : ValueGenerator<DateTime>
{
    public override bool GeneratesTemporaryValues => false;

    public override DateTime Next(EntityEntry entry)
    {
        if (entry is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entry));
        }

        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

how to write the class DbContext

```
public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
{
  GenerateOnUpdate();
  return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
}

public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(
  bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
  {
    GenerateOnUpdate();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
  }

  private void GenerateOnUpdate()
  {
    foreach (EntityEntry entityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
      foreach (PropertyEntry propertyEntry in entityEntry.Properties)
      {
        IProperty property = propertyEntry.Metadata;
        Func<IProperty, IEntityType, ValueGenerator> valueGeneratorFactory = property.GetValueGeneratorFactory();
        bool generatedOnUpdate = (property.ValueGenerated & ValueGenerated.OnUpdate) == ValueGenerated.OnUpdate;
        
        if (!generatedOnUpdate || valueGeneratorFactory == null)
        {
          continue;
        }

        ValueGenerator valueGenerator = valueGeneratorFactory.Invoke(
          property,
          entityEntry.Metadata
        );                    
        propertyEntry.CurrentValue = valueGenerator.Next(entityEntry);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant of Kahbazi's answer, but using nameof() instead of a magic value for the property name. Depending on your usecase you may want to change `DateTime.Now` to `DateTime.UtcNow`.

```
public void Save() {
    var entitiesToCreate = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entity => entity.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
    var entitiesToUpdate = _context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entity => entity.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();

    entitiesToCreate.ForEach(entity => entity.Property(nameof(Entity.CreatedDate)).CurrentValue = DateTime.Now);
    entitiesToUpdate.ForEach(entity => entity.Property(nameof(Entity.UpdatedDate)).CurrentValue = DateTime.Now);

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The underlying Entity looks like this:

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; } = false;

    // ConcurrencyToken
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[]? RowVersion { get; set; } = BitConverter.GetBytes(DateTime.Now.ToBinary());
}
```