# TimeStamp with EF Core 2.1 and Sql Server?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.1

I want to have basically on most of my tables a "Last Updated" column so that I can quickly check when it was last updated.

Right now I been just putting a datetime and every time I do an action in my C# code I will save the new DateTime to update that field. Of course this can lead to me forgetting to do this.

I want something more automatic. I don't need this really for auditing purposes so it does not need to be too advanced.

I tried

```
builder.Property(x => x.RowVersion).IsRowVersion();
```

what should make a timestamp but when I look at in the database I see `0x00000000000007D1` when I thought it would look more like a datetime.

edit

```
 public class CompanyConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Company> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            builder.Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Property<DateTime>("LastUpdated");
        }
    }
```

Comment: [What is difference between datetime and timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460197/what-is-difference-between-datetime-and-timestamp) should be helpful.  TLRD: RowVersion is simply not what-so-ever a value that can be converted to time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you have defined a shadow property `LastModified` for each entity you want that functionality as in your example

```
builder.Property<DateTime>("LastUpdated");
```

and the question is how to update it automatically.

The technique described in the David's answer is outdated. It's still possible to override `SaveChanges` (and `SaveChangesAsync`), but there is IMHO a better approach,  shown in [Populate Created and LastModified automagically in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187146/populate-created-and-lastmodified-automagically-in-ef-core/53188193#53188193). It's interface based approach, but can easily be adjusted for shadow property (or any property - the methods used work for both shadow and explicit properties).

Quick recap: Starting with v2.1, EF Core provides [State change events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#state-change-events):

> New `Tracked` And `StateChanged` events on `ChangeTracker` can be used to write logic that reacts to entities entering the `DbContext` or changing their state.

Here is how you can utilize them. Add the following to your derived context class:

```
void SubscribeStateChangeEvents()
{
    ChangeTracker.Tracked += OnEntityTracked;
    ChangeTracker.StateChanged += OnEntityStateChanged;
}

void OnEntityStateChanged(object sender, EntityStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ProcessLastModified(e.Entry);
}

void OnEntityTracked(object sender, EntityTrackedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.FromQuery)
        ProcessLastModified(e.Entry);
}

void ProcessLastModified(EntityEntry entry)
{
    if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added)
    {
        var property = entry.Metadata.FindProperty("LastModified");
        if (property != null && property.ClrType == typeof(DateTime))
            entry.CurrentValues[property] = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

and add

```
SubscribeStateChangeEvents();
```

to your derived context constructor(s).

And that's all. Once the context is subscribed to these events, it will be notified anytime the entity is initially tracked or its state changes. You are interested only with `Modified` and `Added` state not triggered by query materialization (if you don't need `Added`, then just exclude it from the `if` condition). Then you check if the entity contains `DateTime LastModified` property using the EF Core metadata services and if yes, simply update it with the current date/time.

Comment: Cool this seems to be working, the one thing with these shadow property, what happens if I want to check the value or query based on a certain date? How do I do that in linq? Do I add a LastUpdated property?

Comment: You could use [EF.Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.ef.property?view=efcore-2.1) method to access such fields inside LINQ to Entities query, which means you can do filter, sort, `select` etc. e.g. `db.Set<Company>().Where(e => EF.Property<DateTime>(e, "LastModified") < someDate).OrderByDescending(e => EF.Property<DateTime>(e, "LastModified"))` etc. But if you need that often, adding explicit property would be better. The good thing is, explicit or shadow, the change tracking handling code will be the same.

Comment: So I would have in my config builder.Property<DateTime>("LastUpdated"); and in my model I would have public DateTime LastUpated {get; set;}

Comment: Well, if you have `public DateTime LastUpdated {get; set;}` in the model, you don't need `builder.Property<DateTime>("LastUpdated");` (althought it won't hurt). What I was trying to say was that the code in the answer will work regardless of whether the entity has explicit property or shadow property - as soon as it's called "LastUpdated" and is of type `DateTime`. Think of it like universal code for accessing property, similar to reflection, but using EF Core metadata model.

Comment: Hey sorry to bring this up again but it is not working on one of my modals. I am doing this  var found = dbContext.Tracking.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Token == token);
 found.SomeField = "1541515";
 dbContext.SaveChanges(); but the LastUpdated is not automatically updated. It seems to skip it because of "OnEntityTracked" FromQuery is True

Comment: I guess this could be reguarding your comment about "query materialization" though I thought since I am  updating the entity it would have be considered "modified"

Comment: As part of the `FirstOrDefault` call, yes, it is coming from query and should be skipped (the state should be `Unchanged` anyway). But after setting some field and calling `SaveChanges`, it should go through `OnEntityStateChanged` because the state should change to `Modified`. Check if `dbContext.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` is `true`. If not, you should call `dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();` manually.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern in EF Core for this is to make the "LastUpdated" a [Shadow Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties), and update it during SaveChanges().

See, eg: [Implementing Common Audit Fields with EF Core’s Shadow Property](http://www.fiyazhasan.me/implementing-common-audit-fields-with-ef-cores-shadow-property/)

Comment: So I add "          builder.Property<DateTime>("LastUpdated");" to all my config files? Then where do I override saveChanges? What happens if I do not want all tables to have this lastUpdated on it?

Comment: SaveChanges is a DbContext method.  You override it in your DbContext subtype.  If you don't want all your tables to have the property, you just need to keep track of which ones do and don't, or examine them at runtime as in the linked blog.

Comment: hmm, my db conext file has    class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Employee>  which does not have SaveChanges. Do I need to also add : DbContext to it?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.savechanges?view=efcore-2.1) class documentation, you can override `SaveChanges` method and set the `LastUpdated` values in there, before continuing with `base.SaveChanges()` at the end.

One last piece - inside `SaveChanges` method, you can find the modified/newly added entities using [ChangeTracker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.changetracker?view=efcore-2.1) property.