# ChangeTracker.StateChanged of DbContext gets triggered when calling .Entry()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I implemented similar solution on how we can modify created and updated date upon saving data through EF Core as what is suggested here [Populate Created and LastModified automagically in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187146/populate-created-and-lastmodified-automagically-in-ef-core).

```
void OnEntityStateChanged(object sender, EntityStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewState == EntityState.Modified && e.Entry.Entity is IHasCreationLastModified entity)
        entity.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
}
```

At first I thought this will be triggered only when `SaveChanges()` is called. But apparently it is also called on `Entry()`

```
// Get entity
var student = _dbContext.Students.Find(studentId);

// Modify student object
student.Name = "New student name";

// Called Entry(), trigger ChangeTracker.StateChanged
var entry = _dbContext.Entry(student);

// Doesn't trigger ChangeTracker.StateChanged
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I found that `ChangeTracker.StateChanged` is triggered when `_dbContext.Entry(student)` is called. Then it doesn't get triggered again when `_dbContext.SaveChanges()` is called. And it also passes the condition above `if (e.NewState == EntityState.Modified && e.Entry.Entity is IHasCreationLastModified entity)`.

My assumption why it is not triggered again when `SaveChanges()` is called, because there is no new update to the entity after `Entity()` is called.

This results in the `LastModified` property being assigned when `.Entry(student)` is called, instead of when `.SaveChanges()` is called.

Is there a way to only update `LastModified` property once when `SaveChanges` is called on the scenario above?

Comment: override `public virtual int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)` - there you can access `ChangeTracker`, found all entities with `Modified` state and update their `LastModified` property right before writing to db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you could override you `SaveChanges` method in your dbContext. You could refer to below code that I usually use.

```
public class ForumContext : DbContext
{
    public ForumContext(DbContextOptions<ForumContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    //other settings
    public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    ((BaseEntity)entry.Entity).AddedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    ((BaseEntity)entry.Entity).LastModified = DateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Modified:
                    ((BaseEntity)entry.Entity).LastModified = DateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                    entry.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
    }
```

Comment: from where do i get the base entity

Answer (score 1):

I thought you might like to know why you were getting the the events you saw in your question.

When you execute the line `student.Name = "New student name";`, then, by default, nothing happens because EF Core hasn't called the `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges` method yet so it doesn't know anything has changed.

But the call to `var entry = _dbContext.Entry(student);` then runs a version of the `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges` - see the code below taken from the EF Core code.

```
public virtual EntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>([NotNull] TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
    Check.NotNull<TEntity>(entity, nameof (entity));
    this.CheckDisposed();
    EntityEntry<TEntity> entityEntry = this.EntryWithoutDetectChanges<TEntity>(entity);
    //My comment - this runs a version of the DetectChanges method. 
    this.TryDetectChanges((EntityEntry) entityEntry);
    return entityEntry;
}
```

EF Core's `Entry` method does this because you might ask for the `State` of the entity and therefore it has to call `DetectChanges` to make sure its up to date.

Now, it turns out that if you do the following

```
student.Name = "New student name";
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Then (in EF Core 5 preview, but I think it is the same in EF Core 3.1) you get two events.

1. OldState.EntityState == Unchanged, newState.EntityState == Modified - that is triggered by the call to `DetectChanges`.
2. OldState.EntityState == Modified, newState.EntityState == Unchanged - that is triggered by `SaveChanges` when it set the state to say the database matches the entity class.

If you do the following

```
student.Name = "New student name";
var entry = _dbContext.Entry(student);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Then you would get the same events. The `DetectChanges` would be called twice (once by `Entry` and once by `SaveChanges`), but there is no change in the State on the second call the `DetectChanges`

You can see this in [my unit tests](https://github.com/JonPSmith/EfCoreinAction-SecondEdition/blob/Part2/Test/UnitTests/TestDataLayer/Ch11_ChangeTrackerEvents.cs) in the repo I am writing to support my book [Entity Framework Core in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/entity-framework-core-in-action-second-edition?a_aid=su4utaraxuTre8tuthup). I'm writing the section on these events and found your question and though I would answer it.

I hope it helps you understand what is going on, but I should say that the other answers suggesting overriding `SaveChanges` is a better solution than using these events.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this is really helpful