# EFCore: Changing a property during a StateChange event called from SaveChanges and DetectChanges is not updated

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, event-handling, savechanges

I have an EFCore entity that contains an `UpdatedTime` property that I would like to always have set to `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow` when the entity's `State` changes to `Modified`.

Using sample code [found in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53187146/populate-created-and-lastmodified-automagically-in-ef-core) I created the following event handler:

```
static void OnEntityStateChanged(object? sender, EntityStateChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Entry.Entity is not IHasUpdatedTime entityWithTimestamps)
    {
        return;
    }

    switch (e.Entry.State)
    {
        case EntityState.Modified:
            entityWithTimestamps.UpdatedTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            break;
            // Other cases elided
    }
}
```

In most cases this works as expected.

However, if the case of a very simple entity where only a single `bool` property `IsReady` is changed, it does not work as expected.

The symptoms are:

- The `IsReady` property is updated in an object that was previously returned by a query and tracked, but no EF functions are called
- `SaveChangesAsync` is called
- My `StateChanged` event handler is called
- Inside my event handler, I can see that the Entity is `Modified` and `ChangeTracker.DebugView` shows the `IsReady` property is `Modified` and the value was `false` and is now `true`, as expected
- My code above sets `UpdatedTime`
- `SaveChangesAync` completes and SQL logging shows that only the `IsReady` column is updated, but **NOT** `UpdatedTime` as expected.

Looking at the differences in stack traces between this case and another that works, in the working case it appears that `DetectChanges` is getting called before `SaveChangesAsync`.

My theory is that when a `StateChanged` handler is called from within `DetectChanges`, and that handler changes another property, it is indeterminate on if `DetectChanges` will detect that change before it completes. If the newly changed property had already been "checked", the newly changed property would be missed and thus not updated in the database. Since in this case it is `SaveChangesAsync` that is calling `DetectChanges`, there is no other chance for it to be called again.

With some more debugging, I can see that `ChangeTracker.DebugView` shows the `UpdatedTime` `Property` as changed from the original, but it is not "Modified". Further debugging into the internals shows that `Property.IsModified` is `false`.

When I change the above code to be as follows:

```
    case EntityState.Modified:
        entityWithTimestamps.UpdatedTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
        if (!e.Entry.Property("UpdatedTime").IsModified)
        {
            e.Entry.Property("UpdatedTime").IsModified = true;
        }
        break;
```

Now the `IsReady` property is reliably updated.

Is this analysis correct?

Is there a better way to handle this other than modifying internal state?

Is this a defect in Change Detection? Should the change of an unmodified property in a `StateChanged` handler be detected?

Comment: I have the same issue, and my code is from the Official documentation. I would expect it to work....

Answer (score 1):

I found this issue on github about this:
https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/3888

The proposed workaround is setting the new value like this:

```
e.Entry.Property(nameof(Entity.ChangedAt)).CurrentValue = DateTime.Now;
```

It worked for me.