# Fill elements on save

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, autofill, savechanges

I'm looking how to make EF core to fill the elements automatically.
I have a DbDirectory Object with a CreatedBy type User.
On the creation I fill the CreatedById.
How to make EF core to fill the CreatedBy automatically on the SaveChangesAsync?
more Details are present in the screen

[image]

This is my context rule

```
builder.Entity<DbDirectory>().HasOne(directory => directory.CreatedBy);
```

Those are my attributes

```
public int CreatedById { get; set; }
public new User.User CreatedBy { get; set; }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set created date and Modified Date to enitites in DB first approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285948/how-to-set-created-date-and-modified-date-to-enitites-in-db-first-approach)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv if I understand, I have to override the default saveChanges?

Comment: Yes, it is right way.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv ok that's a bit sad thanks for your help