# Can you pass current user into dbcontext using asp.net core DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am currently using DI for my context like below.

```
services.AddTransient<APDatabase.DBContext>(provider =>
{
    return new APDatabase.DBContext();
});
```

Is it possible to pass the current logged in user into this? I currently get the user in the controller as follows.

```
public NavigationController(APDatabase.DBContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    this._context = context;
    this._currentUser = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
}
```

I could then set this as a property on the context in the contsructor of each controller. This is the only way I can see of doing this currently but would prefer to have the DI handle it for me if possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get user information in DbContext using Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401026/how-to-get-user-information-in-dbcontext-using-net-core)

Comment: Also, please don't register the DbContext like you are. Use `Services.AddDbContext()` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use DI to register the `DBContext` by `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>` instead of `return new APDatabase.DBContext();`.

Follow steps below:

1. DbContext:

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
   {
       private HttpContext _httpContext;
       public string CurrentUser => _httpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
       public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
           IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
           : base(options)
       {
           _httpContext = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
       }        
   }
   ```
2. Register `DbContext`

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(
           Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
   ```
3. UseCase

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       private readonly ApplicationDbContext _appDbContext;
       public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
       {
           _appDbContext = applicationDbContext;
       }        
       public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
       {
           var user = _appDbContext.CurrentUser;
           return View();
       }

   }
   ```