# IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity shows all null properties in CurrentUserService service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, identity, httpcontext, clean-architecture

I am trying to use [Jason Taylor's Clean Architecture Template](https://github.com/JasonGT/CleanArchitecture), this template uses NSwag to automatically create a TypeScript Client (Angular), but I don't need to create a TS client, so my main goal is to replace it with Razor Pages. I've been able to achieve this to a high grade, but I'm having trouble with the *CurrentUserService* whenever it gets instantiated it is supposed to set the UserId in this line:

```
UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

This is the full *CurrentUserService*:

```
using CleanREC0.Application.Common.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace CleanREC0.WebUI.Services
{
    public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
    {
        public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        }

        public string UserId { get; }
    }
}
```

The first time even the HttpContext is *null* and that's fine, since everything is initializing, but the subsequent calls always return *null* on all of *httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity* properties, The User Shows an *Identity* alright but all of it's properties and claims are *null* or *Yield no results*, even with a user properly logged on.

Here is a list of things I've done to the template:

- Got rid of *NSwag* and everything *TypeScript* Related
- Got rid of *IdentityServer*
- Replaced *ApiAuthorizationDbContext* for *IdentityDbContext*

This is my StartUp class:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddApplication();
            services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration, Environment);    

            services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>(); //I have added this line on as suggested on other post, but made no difference.


            services.AddHealthChecks()
                .AddDbContextCheck<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<IApplicationDbContext>());
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();
            app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the *AddApplication* that gets called from *ConfigureServices*:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddApplication(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPerformanceBehaviour<,>));
            services.AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestValidationBehavior<,>));

            return services;
        }
```

And the *AddInfrastructure* that also gets called there:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
                    b => b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)));

            services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>());

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            if (environment.IsEnvironment("Test"))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                services.AddTransient<IDateTime, DateTimeService>();
                services.AddTransient<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();
                services.AddTransient<ICsvFileBuilder, CsvFileBuilder>();
            }

            services.AddAuthentication();

            return services;
        }
```

Everything else seems to be working fine. At *Razor Page* level the *User* variable and it's *Identity* contain all expected information and claims.

I'm sure I'm missing something, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show us the code where you're accessing the context? `UserId =...`

Comment: @Train I've added the full CurrentUserService code, I hope that's what you meant. Thanks for taking the time to review my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1212451/9936356

Comment: [Authorize]
  just add this property on controller

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LinkedListT's link in the comments got me in the right direction.

The link points to an answer which explains this:

> under the ASP.NET MVC framework, the HttpContext (and therefore
>   HttpContext.Session) is not set when the controller class is
>   contructed as you might expect, but it set ("injected") later by the
>   ControllerBuilder class.

The *CurrentUserService* class that comes with the template I'm using tries to read the user claims in the constructor, so I moved the code to the property's getter, which executes until latter when the property is actually used, by then all claims and properties are well populated.

My new *CurrentUserService* looks like this:

```
using CleanREC0.Application.Common.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.Security.Claims;

namespace CleanREC0.WebUI.Services
{
    public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
    {
        private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public string UserId { get { return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier); }}
    }
}
```